# Does Spring Integration provide something like a metric-channel-interceptor that can be logged within a flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm looking for an easy way on some of my flows to be able to log when some "event" occurs.
In my simple case an "event" might be whenever any message flows down a channel, or whenever a certain # of messages flow down a channel, I'd like to print out some info to a log file.

I know there currently is a `logging-channel-adapter` but in the case just described I'd need to be able to tailor my own log message and I'd also need to have some sort of counter or metrics keeping track of things (so the `expression` on the adapter wouldn't suffice since that grants access to the `payload` but not info about the channel or flow).

I'm aware that Spring Integration already exposes a lot of metrics to JMX via `ManagedResources` and `MetricType` and `ManagedMetric`s.
I've also watched Russell's "Managing and Monitoring Spring Integration Applications" YouTube video several times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TetfR7ULnA8
and I realize that Spring Integration component metrics can be polled via `jmx-attribute-polling-channel-adapter`

There are certainly many ways to get what I'm after. 
A few examples:

- ServiceAdapter that has a counter in it that also has a reference to a logger
- Hook into the advice-chain of a poller
- Poll JMX via jmx-attribute-polling-channel-adapter

It might be useful however to offer a few components that users could put **into the middle of a flow** that could provide some basic functionality to easily satisfy the use-case I described.
Sample flow might look like:
`inbound-channel-adapter ->  metric-logging-channel-interceptor -> componentY -> outbound-channel-adapter`

Very high-level such a component might look like a hybrid of the `logging-channel-adapter` and a `ChannelInterceptor` with a few additional fields:

```
    <int:metric-logging-channel-interceptor>
        id=""
        order="" 
        phase=""
        auto-startup=""
        ref=""
        method=""
        channel=""
        outchannel=""
        log-trigger-expression="(SendCount % 10) = 0"
        level=""
        logger-name=""
        log-full-message=""
        expression="" 
         />
```

Internally the class implementing that would need to keep a few basic stats, I think the ones exposed on messageChannel would be a good  (i.e. SendCount, MaxSendDuration, etc). 
The `log-trigger-expression` and `expression` attributes would need access to the internal counters as well.

Please let me know if there is something that already does what I'm describing or if I'm overcomplicating this.  If it does not currently exist though I think that being able to quickly drop a component into a flow without having to write a custom `ServiceActivator` just for logging purposes provides benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. You can already do something similar with a selective wire-tap...

```
<si:publish-subscribe-channel id="seconds">
    <si:interceptors>
        <si:wire-tap channel="thresholdLogger" selector="selector" />
    </si:interceptors>
</si:publish-subscribe-channel>

<bean id="selector" class="org.springframework.integration.filter.ExpressionEvaluatingSelector">
    <constructor-arg 
        value="@mbeanServer.getAttribute('org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=seconds', 'SendCount') > 5" />
</bean>

<si:logging-channel-adapter id="thresholdLogger" />
```

There are a couple of things going on here...

1. The stats are actually held in the MBean for the channel, not the channel itself so the expression has to get the value via the MBean server.
2. Right now, the wire-tap doesn't support `selector-expression`, just `selector` so I had to use a reference to an expression evaluating selector. It would be a useful improvement to support `selector-expression` directly.
3. Even though the selector in this example acts on the stats for the tapped channel, it can actually reference any MBean.

I can see some potential improvements here.

1. Support `selector-expression`.
2. Maintain the stats in the channel itself instead of the MBean so we can just use `@channelName.sendCount > 5`.

Feel free to open JIRA 'improvement' issue(s).

Hope that helps.